# select subquery using data from the select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have two tables, `headers` and `lines`.  I need to grab the `batch_submission_date` from the header table, but sometimes a query for `batch_id` will return a `null` for batch_submission_date, but will also return a parent_batch_id, and if we query THAT parent_batch_id as a batch_id, it will then return the correct batch_submission_date.

e.g.

```
SELECT t1.batch_id, 
    t1.parent_batch_id, 
    t2.batch_submission_date 
FROM db.headers t1, db.lines t2 
WHERE t1.batch_id = '12345';
```

`output = 12345, 99999, null`

Then we use that parent batch_id as a batch_id :

```
SELECT t1.batch_id, 
    t1.parent_batch_id, 
    t2.batch_submission_date
FROM db.headers t1, db.lines t2
WHERE t1.batch_id = '99999';
```

`and we get output = 99999,99999,'2018-01-01'`

So I'm trying to write a query that will do this for me - anytime a batch_id's batch_submission_date is null, we find that batch_id's parent batch_id and query that instead.

This was my idea - but I just get back null both for `bp_batch_submission_date` and for `new_submission_date`.

```
SELECT
    t1.parent_id as parent_id,
    t1.BATCH_ID as bp_batch_id,
    t2.BATCH_LINE_NUMBER as bp_batch_li,
    t1.BATCH_SUBMISSION_DATE as bp_batch_submission_date,

    CASE 
        WHEN t1.BATCH_SUBMISSION_DATE is null
    THEN
        (SELECT a.BATCH_SUBMISSION_DATE 
        FROM 
        db.headers a,
        db.lines b 
        WHERE 
            a.SD_BATCH_HEADERS_SKEY = b.SD_BATCH_HEADERS_SKEY   
            and a.parent_batch_id = bp_batch_id
            and b.batch_line_number = bp_batch_li
        ) END as new_submission_date

FROM    
    db.headers t1,
    db.lines t2 
WHERE
    t1.SD_BATCH_HEADERS_SKEY = t2.SD_BATCH_HEADERS_SKEY   
    and (t1.BATCH_ID = '12345' or t1.PARENT_BATCH_ID = '12345') 
    and t2.BATCH_LINE_NUMBER = '1'              
GROUP BY
    t2.BATCH_CLAIM_LINE_STATUS_DESC,
    t1.PARENT_BATCH_ID,
    t1.BATCH_ID,
    t2.BATCH_LINE_NUMBER,
    t1.BATCH_SUBMISSION_DATE;
```

is what I'm trying to do possible?  using the `bp_batch_id` and `bp_batch_li` variables

Comment: Maybe your where clause is wrong? If you post tables and data we can help you more

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE (common table expression) to avoid redundant code, then use `coalesce()` to find parent date in case of null. In your first queries you didn't attach joining condition between two tables, I assumed it's based on `sd_batch_headers_skey` like in last query.

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=86326c1cf664fe3efaff275c2184c17d)</sup>**

```
with t as (
    select h.batch_id, h.parent_batch_id, l.batch_submission_date bs_date
      from headers h
      join lines l on l.sd_batch_headers_skey = h.sd_batch_headers_skey 
                  and l.batch_line_number = '1' )
select batch_id, parent_batch_id, 
       coalesce(bs_date, (select bs_date from t x where x.batch_id = t.parent_batch_id)) bs_date
  from t 
  where batch_id = 12345;
```

You could use simpler syntax with `connect by` and `level <= 2` but if in your data there are really rows containing same ids (`99999`, `99999`) then we get cycle error.